# Embedded Image and Text In an SSRS Textbox

Tags: image, reporting-services, textbox

I need to print State->City on a SSRS Report Header. The city value might be present or might not be present.

I used the following expression in a textbox :

**=First(Fields!State.Value, "dsStateName") &  IIF(IsNothing(First(Fields!City.Value, "dsCityName"))   or First(Fields!City.Value, "dsCityName")="","",
 " -> "  & First(FieldsCity.Value, "dsCityName"))**

It is working fine but the thing is I would like to replace "->" with a proper image of an arrow. Is there a way to combine text and image in a textbox.

I tried using two texboxes for the State and  City names respectively and an image for the arrow but the problem is as the state name is of variable length it leaves blank area between the the statename and the image.

Thanks
Sam

Comment: Would the two-textbox solution be acceptable if you right-justified the "State" textbox?

Comment: Well not really. All of it has to be left aligned. Thanks for trying